# JS module - Where in the devtools can I see my currently instantiated variables in their current state?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Been looking for a couple hours now for related SO threads or other info, haven't found any.

My webtool uses JS modules for its scripts, in case that's relevant.
In my index.js, I have several top-level functions, variables, etc. I'd like to be able to manually reference and console.log() them from the devtools console, however I'm not sure how to actually do that. I also can't find my variables and other declared stuff anywhere in the Memory tab of devtools, even when I search for my function names.

For example, I have an array called "currentInstantiatedKeybinds" declared in my index.js file. All attempts to log it or its contents to the console have failed.
Additionally, I have a top-level function that won't execute when I call it in the console by name; I get a "ReferenceError: functionName not defined at :1:1".
How do I actually reference it without having to put a debugger or breakpoint into the program, then manually reloading the tool so that the variable/function I want to see is re-evaluated? Can you not just see the current state of your variables?

Tangentially, in the Memory tab, where does the Window object actually store the things you declare in your scripts? Like where exactly is all of that kept? I see a few things I've declared, such as class object instances I've made when I take a snapshot, but haven't been able to find any of my variables or functions.

Thanks!

Comment: [Similar](/q/58679410)  [questions](/q/59737257) [here](/q/62763721)

Answer (score 2):

### Block Statements

Make sure that your variable is at the top of the scope (or assign it to window), and then it becomes accessible from devtools. Also, make sure you do the same for functions. An issue that I would have was that I was unable to access the functions from inside `window.onload`. For example,

```js
let jack = 'I am jack!';
{
    let jill = 'I am jill!';
}
console.log(jack); //=> 'I am jack!'
console.log(jill); //=> Uncaught ReferenceError: jill is not defined
```

OR

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let jack = 'I am jack!'
    let jill = 'I am jill!'
}

console.log(jack); //=> Uncaught ReferenceError: jack is not defined
console.log(jill); //=> Uncaught ReferenceError: jill is not defined
```

But, what if I want to access `jack` or `jill` outside of the block?

```js
let jill;
let jack = 'I am jack!';
{
    jill = 'I am jill!';
}
console.log(jack); //=> 'I am jack!'
console.log(jill); //=> 'I am jill!'
```

OR

```js
let jack = 'I am jack!';
{
    window.jill = 'I am jill!';
}
console.log(jack); //=> 'I am jack!'
console.log(jill); //=> 'I am jill!'
```

Of course, the top one lexically binds `jill` to the string `'I am jill!'` and the bottom one just assigns it as a property of window.

### Other Troubleshooting

It is also important to make sure that your script file `index.js` is correctly included into the file `index.html`. For example,

```html
<script src='index.js'></script>
```

OR

```html
<script src='./index.js'></script>
```

Make sure that the `type` attribute is equal to `module` or `text/javascript` or not included at all. If you want to wait for the page to load before executing a script add `defer` into the tag:

```html
<!-- Deferred Script -->
<script src='./index.js' defer></script>

<!-- Module Script -->
<script src='./index.js' type='module'></script>

<!-- Normal Script -->
<script src='./index.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<!-- Incorrect Script -->
<script src='./index.js' type='text/plain'></script>

<!-- Incorrect Script -->
<script src='./index.js' type='blah'></script>
```

### Side Note

I hope that my answered helped you out and this fixes the problem.